# how to compile dynamic html code including Angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ajax

```
<div id="divProductItems"></div>
```

above div will be filled with some html + angularjs elements later after an ajax call from a seperate js file. But angularjs codes are not working properly at the moment. how can I fix this problem

```
function getProductItems() {
    var productSelected = $('#hdnSelectedProducts').val();
    callActionWithJson("/Item/ProductItem", function (data) {
        $("#divProductItems").html(data); // here I add the dynamic code to the above div and (data) contains the dynamic html + angularjs directives
        filterProductItem();
    }, null, "pricingLevelId", $("#ddlPricingLevel").val(), "searchItem", $("#txtSearchItem").val(), "productId", (productSelected.length != null ? productSelected : 0));
}
```

Comment: use `$compile()` to compile  the dynamic angular code

Comment: I saw that in a similar type question please tell me that in detail I couldn't fix it with that. how to use $compile() ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile the html you are inserting into the `<div>` take a look at the `$compile` documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

Need to inject `$compile` in your controller.

```
$compile($('#divProductItems'))($scope);
```

Comment: is it just I need to put this within my controller ?

Comment: AFAIK you have to write a directive for that

Comment: Yes. It should work if you put this in your controller after your DOM is updated.